# Convert \r text to \n so readlines() works as intended

Tags: python, readline

In Python, you can read a file and load its lines into a list by using

```
f = open('file.txt','r')
lines = f.readlines()
```

Each individual line is delimited by `\n` but if the contents of a line have `\r` then it is not treated as a new line. I need to convert all `\r` to `\n` and get the correct list `lines`.

If I do `.split('\r')` inside the `lines` I'll get lists inside the list.

I thought about opening a file, replace all `\r` to `\n`, closing the file and reading it in again and then use the `readlines()` but this seems wasteful.

How should I implement this?

Comment: Actually, if you have a mix of `\n` and `\r` newlines, and if the latter occur within the "real" lines separated by `\n`, then getting lists inside the list appears to me to be the Right Thing.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
f = open('file.txt','rU')
```

This opens the file with Python's [universal newline support](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) and `\r` is treated as an end-of-line.

Comment: ...although this feature is deprecated and should not be used in new code according to the Python documentation.

Comment: Thanks! This works as intended and is sufficient for me.

Tim, what would be the correct way to do it now?

Comment: In Python 3.x universal newline support is on by default, so you don't have to do anything.

Comment: this isn't working for me unfortunately every time I call readlines() on mac my list's length is always 1!

Comment: @advocate, What version of Python?  You should probably open a new question with all the details of your problem.

Comment: found the problem. readlines() perpetually fails for me but read().split("\r") performs the same functionality and works. also .split("\n") fails perpetually for me on very file as well for probably the same reason that .readlines() doesn't work. This took me days to figure out! this is my first time working professionally on a mac and tripped me up for a long time unfortunately. this is python 2.7.5 on OSX 10.9.1. Opening the file for 'rU' did NOT fix my newline / carriage return problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a concern, open in binary format and convert with this code:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    s = f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n').replace('\r', '\n')
    lines = s.split('\n')
```