# Scilab mgetl (or python readlines): how to read line if the text file has \r instead of \n

Tags: python, file, newline, readline, scilab

I have a text file in which the newline is specified by \r and not \n. So while using mgetl() in Scilab or readlines() in python, the whole file is read. The file is really huge and I want to avoid reading it entirely. How to do that?

Interestingly, when I tried [universal newline support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) as recommended in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785233/convert-r-text-to-n-so-readlines-works-as-intended) post, the command converted all '\r' characters to '\n' and then read all the lines! So the problem remains unsolved for me both in Scilab and python. The issue is that I need solution in both languages! :/

Please help..

Comment: I'm confused; what's insufficient about universal newline support?

Comment: Universal newline support converts '\r' to '\n', but only after reading the whole text file. I want to read line after line.

Comment: Could you paste your Python code and a snippet of your data?

Answer (score 0):

In Scilab language, you can use the `mfscanf()` function as follows:

```
cr = ascii(13);
txt = "abcdefgh" + cr + "ijkl" + cr + cr + "mnopq";
mputl(txt, "test.txt")

fid = mopen("test.txt", "r");
row = 0;
while row <> []
    row = mfscanf(fid, "%s\r")
end
mclose(fid)
```

This will read one by one the rows ended with / separated by `\r`:

```
-->     while row <> []
  >         row = mfscanf(fid, "%s\r")
  >     end
 row  = 
  "abcdefgh"
 row  = 
  "ijkl"
 row  = 
  "mnopq"
 row  = 
    []
```

Note that empty rows are ignored (consecutive ascii(13) are "merged").